# Error installing Heroku Plugin to Eclipse 3.8.1

Tags: eclipse, heroku

getting the following when trying to talk to Heroku via Eclipse. No problem on the command line toolkit.

This is on Ubuntu 13.04 Eclipse 3.8.1

I can serve the url with no problem. Anyone come across this?

```
{{Error
Sat Aug 24 16:49:46 BST 2013
Unable to read repository at https://eclipse-plugin.herokuapp.com/install/site.xml.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.throwSSLException(Handshaker.java:1274)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1565)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$GzipGetMethod.execute(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1129)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.readInto(FileReader.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatesite.UpdateSite.loadActualSiteFile(UpdateSite.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatesite.UpdateSite.load(UpdateSite.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatesite.metadata.UpdateSiteMetadataRepositoryFactory.initializeRepository(UpdateSiteMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatesite.metadata.UpdateSiteMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(UpdateSiteMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Could not create EC public key
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:169)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1057)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:218)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_CreateObject(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.generatePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:233)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:164)
    ... 43 more
}}
```

Comment: FYI, I've had a look at this [bug fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1006776) and tried it, but didn't seem to work

Comment: Java version 1.7.0_25